# The Trace Ratio Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, data-analysis, data-mining

For two m × m positive semidefinite matrices $S_p$ and $S_l$, the trace ratio problem is defined as
finding a m × d (d < m) transform matrix W∗ that satisfies $$
W^{*}=\underset{W^{T} W=I}{\arg \max } \frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[W^{T} S_{p} W\right]}{\operatorname{Tr}\left[W^{T} S_{l} W\right]}
$$ and the optimum trace ratio value $$
\lambda^{*}=\max _{W^{T} W=I} \frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[W^{T} S_{p} W\right]}{\operatorname{Tr}\left[W^{T} S_{l} W\right]}
$$
How can I prove that this problem  does not have a closed-form solution?

Comment: Could you give a reference for understanding the why and the how of this trace ratio ?

Comment: Sure. H. Wang, S. Yan, D. Xu, X. Tang, and T. Huang, “Trace Ratio vs. Ratio Trace for Dimensionality Reduction,” Proceedings of Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2007

Comment: Thank you very much...